# How to find a countable set satisfying some property

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau=\{G\subset \mathbb R: 0\in \mathbb R\setminus G$ or $\mathbb R\setminus G$ is finite $\}$ and let $\tau_u$ be the usual topology on $\mathbb R$. I want to show that if $f:(\mathbb R,\tau)\to (\mathbb R, \tau_u)$ is continuous, then there exists a countable subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R\setminus A$.

To solve the problem I tried as follows:
Let for all $B\subset \mathbb R$ for which $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x\in B$, we have $\mathbb R\setminus B$ is uncountable. Now how to show the contradiction? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: There was a seriuos mistake...now it is corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By continuity, for each $n\in\mathbb N$ there is a $\tau$-neighborhood $G_n$ of $0$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|\lt\frac1n$ whenever $x\in G_n$. Then $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}(\mathbb R\setminus G_n)$ is countable, and $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R\setminus A$.